# SQL query syntax incorrect?

Tags: query, sql

This doesn't give me an error, but it also doesn't display any results.  I'm trying to display only the entries that don't have a relationship.  My relationship field is field_id_57, and I only want to display entries from channel_id_30.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_channel_data WHERE field_id_57 IS NULL && channel_id = '30'"}

content should display here

{/exp:query{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since channel entry titles & data are stored in different tables, you will need to `inner join` the two tables together to get the **Title** of the entry. Something like this:

```
SELECT ecd.entry_id,
ect.entry_id,
ect.title 
FROM exp_channel_data AS ecd
INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles AS ect
ON ecd.entry_id = ect.entry_id
WHERE ecd.field_id_57 IS NULL
AND ecd.channel_id = '30'
```